# Remove first and last two record from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

```
data:[
  { user: "2016-04-14", avg_: "13", new: "32511.20" },
  { user: "2016-04-21", avg_: "32", new: "32779.17" },
  { user: "2016-04-22", avg_: "32", new: "32898.40" },
  { user: "2016-04-23", avg_: "32", new: "32903.11" },
  { user: "2016-04-24", avg_: "32", new: "329" },
  { user: "2016-04-25", avg_: "3298", new: "32962.78" }
];
```

I tried and it successfully removed last two elements

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    var s = data.splice(-1, i);
    console.log(s);
}
```

Now, I don't want to repeat this logic to remove first two any idea ?

Comment: `input.splice(-2, 2); input.splice(0, 2);`?

Comment: if you need to save the spliced items, `var firstTwo = data.splice(0,2), lastTwo = data.splice(-2, 2);` no loop required

Comment: ahh its fine i got the answer thanks for your response :) @Bravo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply get the first two and also last elements without the loop by only using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
const data = [
        {user: "2016-04-14", avg_: "13", new: "32511.20"},
        {user: "2016-04-21", avg_: "32", new: "32779.17"},
        {user: "2016-04-22", avg_: "32", new: "32898.40"},
        {user: "2016-04-23", avg_: "32", new: "32903.11"},
        {user: "2016-04-24", avg_: "32", new: "329"},
        {user: "2016-04-25", avg_: "3298", new: "32962.78"}
      ];
    
    const res = [...data.slice(0, 2), ...data.slice(-2)]
console.log(res);
```

or if you want to remove the first and last two and keep the rest, you can write it like

```js
const data = [
        {user: "2016-04-14", avg_: "13", new: "32511.20"},
        {user: "2016-04-21", avg_: "32", new: "32779.17"},
        {user: "2016-04-22", avg_: "32", new: "32898.40"},
        {user: "2016-04-23", avg_: "32", new: "32903.11"},
        {user: "2016-04-24", avg_: "32", new: "329"},
        {user: "2016-04-25", avg_: "3298", new: "32962.78"}
      ];
    
    const res = data.slice(2, -2)
console.log(res);
```

Comment: did you mean `splice` - the OP definitely asks to *remove* the first 2 and last 2

Comment: @Bravo From what it looks like in his example, he prints the removed elements and hence I suggested slice

Comment: @Bravo, I added the other part to it too in my answer

Comment: nope, your code still does nothing to change `data` - nothing is removed from `data` - perhaps you want to copy the code in the comments?

Comment: @Bravo, Its not a right idea to mutate the data in most cases and its better to perform this operation in an immutable way and hence clone and return what you need

Comment: Why isn't it the right idea to mutate data, how do you know what data is used for? that seems to be exactly what the OP wants! The first word in the question title is **remove** not **get**

Comment: @Bravo thats is because when you mutate the data any reference to this same data will also be changed and it might lead to unexpected behaviour. Hence I purposefully used slice instead of splice

Comment: well, you seem to know better than the OP what he wants - your code doesn't remove anything, but apparently that's correct!! I'm surprised - do you work with each other or something?

Comment: @Bravo, no we don't work with each other or know each other, I just wrote an answer according to the best practises that should be followed

Answer (score 1):

Very simple way - just call these functions:

```
arr.pop():
arr.pop();
arr.shift();
arr.shift();
```

And the two first and two last elements will be removed.

Comment: so `arr.pop();arr.pop();arr.shift();arr.shift();`

Comment: Yes exactly @Bravo

Comment: I don't get it, your answer is correct, it removes the first two and last two items from the array like was asked in the question. I'm new here, and this question/answer has me stumped as to how this place works. Apparently you're supposed to tell the OP they don't want to do what they clear stated they want to do - is that right?

Comment: @Bravo You tell the OP the problem in their code, and the fixed code/lines of code that does what they want it to do.

Comment: they seem to have accepted the answer - as I said, just trying to get a handle on this place